# Why do memcache calls (app engine) get interrupted?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, memcached, interrupted-exception

I'm using App Engine (java) with MemCache. When I try out my code all seems to work fine. But when I increase the load on my instances I sometimes get the following stacktrace.

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Unexpected failure
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:106)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:186)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.gameclientendpoint.data.GameDataMerger.mergeGameData(GameDataMerger.java:52)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.gameclientendpoint.endpoints.ActiveGamesEndpoint.getMergedGameData(ActiveGamesEndpoint.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.gcp.NamespaceFilter.doFilter(NamespaceFilter.java:31)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Unexpected failure
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:49)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.datastore.DataManagerGame.getGame(DataManagerGame.java:39)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.datastore.DataManagerGame.getGameFromActiveGame(DataManagerGame.java:21)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.datastore.DataManagerGame$1.call(DataManagerGame.java:31)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.datastore.DataManagerGame$1.call(DataManagerGame.java:28)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.background.BackGroundTasks$ObjectifyCallable.call(BackGroundTasks.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:605)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:393)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:42)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    ... 9 more
```

When I look at the stacktrace I see that the MemcacheService.get(...) method is interrupted. But I have no idea why. The entire call was less then the 60 second limit.

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: How often does this happen and is your load creating 'hot' keys?  Memcache can (occasionally?) throw a `MemcacheServiceException`, which you can handle by registering a [ConsistentErrorHandler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/ConsistentErrorHandler#interface-consistenterrorhandler)

Comment: It does not happen a lot, but I see a couple of them in every load test. 
I'm not sure what you mean by 'hot' keys? What are those?

Comment: if you're hitting the same key with high traffic, the key is called hot key

Comment: Then I guess I'm creating 'hot' keys. But why is that a problem? The main idea from MemCache is that you should load data from it that is frequent used, isn't?